# FireBase sendMessage Function update to v1 Google Cloud Endpoint

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints

So... this morning... I got an email saying:

> Our records show that you own projects with App Engine applications or
>   Cloud Functions that are still calling the pre-GA v0.1 and v1beta1
>   endpoints of the App Engine and Cloud Functions metadata server.
>
> We’re writing to let you know that these legacy endpoints are
>   scheduled to be turned down on April 30, 2020. After April 30, 2020,
>   requests to the v0.1 and v1beta1 endpoints will no longer be
>   supported, and may return HTTP 404 NOT FOUND responses.

I'm only using Firebase Functions to send messages... and the email went on to identify my sendMessage function as the culprit. But I can't... for the life of me... figure out WHERE I need to update the endpoints.  My sendMessage function is as follows:

```
exports.sendMessage = functions.database.ref('/messages/{receiverUid}/{senderUid}/{msgId}')
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
      const message = change.after.val().body;
      const receiverUid = change.after.val().receiverUid;
      const senderUid = change.after.val().senderUid;
      const msgId = change.after.val().msgId;
      if (!change.after.val()) {
        return console.log('Sender ', senderUid, 'receiver ', receiverUid, 'message ', message);
      }
      console.log('We have a new message: ', message, 'for: ', receiverUid);
```

I've tried following some of the Curl suggestions from this link: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/migrating-to-v1-metadata-server

...but every time I try one of them I get:

> curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'metadata.google.internal'

So... at this point... I have no idea what it is I'm supposed to change or where I'm supposed to look. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I got it also. Please update if you found any solution. Thanks

Comment: @tuledev I believe what you have to do is go INSIDE your "functions" directory and run: npm install --save firebase-functions@latest Doing that and updating to the latest version of Node (I was on 10.3 but the latest is like 12). Is what I did. Of course I still don't know how to check my endpoints... So it's hard for me to know that for sure.

Comment: I am facing this issue now. But i want to check the version of service endpoint is whether v0.1 or v1beta1. I have checked gcloud documentation but really I am not getting anything. Please help me with this.

Comment: You won't be able to. There's literally no reliable way to check. They don't actually give you the tools to do it. You just have to look at one of the answers below and update to the latest version of... well... EVERYTHING. But mainly "functions" and "firebase admin". Make sure you do this in the correct directory.

Comment: Thank you @mysticcola, I will make sure to do in the correct directory by following the below answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same problem, and didn't see any of the libraries I was using listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/migrating-to-v1-metadata-server#supported-google-libraries).

In my case, the culprit turned out to be `firebase-admin`.  I was using version 7.3.0, and I found this gem:

```
$ grep -rni "computeMetadata/" *
firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:30:var GOOGLE_METADATA_SERVICE_PATH = '/computeMetadata/v1beta1/instance/service-accounts/default/token';
```

So, I updated my Cloud Functions libraries as shown [here](http://%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff):

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
npm install firebase-admin@latest --save-exact
```

and then, voila!

```
$ grep -rni "computeMetadata/" *
node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:30:var GOOGLE_METADATA_SERVICE_PATH = '/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token';
```

Then I redeployed and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I searched at the https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions repo latest version (3.3.0), and I found the file: spec/fixtures/https.ts. Inside this file there are some mock functions, which use the old: /computeMetadata/v1beta1 endpoint.

This might mean that firebase-functions modules package should be updated to use the /computeMetadata/v1 endpoint instead.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report with them. Hopefully they update the repo: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/580

Answer (score 1):

Fwiw I found this old dependency in `package.json` was dragging in other very old packages:

```
"@google-cloud/functions-emulator": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
```

In particular it brought in `gcs-resumable-upload` v 0.10.2, which is below the v 0.13.0 recommended by google (see https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/migrating-to-v1-metadata-server#apps-to-update).  Probably others too.

The fix was to either:

- remove `@google-cloud/functions-emulator`, or
- switch to its modern replacement, `@google-cloud/functions-framework`

Comment: Okay.  I went with option 3: Which was to install the newest version of gcs-resumable-upload which is currently all the way up to v2.3.0 (my previous version was, indeed, v0.10.2) but my problem still remains: I have NO IDEA how to check if that was even the module causing the problem. Someone else pointed out an outdated endpoint in one of the spec fixtures. But I still don't know of a method to really check what's going on.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to find the conflicts.  I compared the package-lock.json with googles (long) list of apps-to-update, and was lucky enough to spot the offending package (s) and track them to a common source.  There should be ^h^h^h probably is an automated way to do that!  (also, afact just loading the newer one might not be enough; an old module may reference an older version and npm will pull them both in)

Comment: The new version points to: return `https://${this.apiEndpoint}/upload/storage/v1/b`; So that's cool. But for all we know? There could be FIFTY modules pointing to the old one. I think, at the end of the day, Google needs to update firebase-functions. I mean there's nothing that WE can do... and they haven't really given us the tools to even check how many modules might be pointing to the old endpoints.  I mean it's Google's mess in the end... so they're going to have to fix it BEFORE this expiration date.